# What does "new Classname*[]" mean?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a class:

```
class WorkerThread
{
public:
    unsigned virtual run()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Defined in the header. Now in another class I create an object of this type:

```
WorkerThread **workerQueue;
```

Which is actually a pointer to pointer... OK, all good until now.
Now, how should I read this:

```
workerQueue = new WorkerThread*[maxThreads];
```

What is the meaning of the `*` after the ClassName (`WorkerThread`) and the array format?

Comment: `(WorkerThread*)[maxThreads]`. Much clearer now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an allocation of an array of `WorkerThread` pointers.

For instance:

```
size_t maxThreads = 3;
WorkerThread** workerQueue = new WorkerThread*[maxThreads];
```

`workerQueue[0]` is a `WorkerThread*`, as is `WorkerThread[1]` and `WorkerThread[2]`.

These pointers, currently have not been initialized.

Later you may see something like this:

```
for(size_t x = 0; x < maxThreads; ++x)
{
   workerQueue[x] = new WorkerThread(...);

   //beginthreadex_, CreateThread, something....
}
```

I will tell you, that all of these raw pointers are just memory leaks waiting to happen unless carefully handled.  A preferred method would be to use a `std::vector` to some smart pointer of `WorkerThread` objects.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will make it a little clearer to understand:

```
typedef WorkerThread* PointerToWorkerThread;

PointerToWorkerThread *workerQueue;

workerQueue = new PointerToWorkerThread[maxThreads];
```